# A $T_2$ space is locally compact iff it has a base $\beta $ s.t $\forall B\in \beta $ we have $\bar B$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A $T_2$ space is locally compact iff it has a base $\beta $ s.t $\forall B\in \beta $ we have
$\bar B$ is compact.
My definition of locally compact is that $\forall x\in X$ has a compact neighborhood in $X$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ So let $ U$ be an open set in $X$, we show that $U$ is equal to the union of basic open sets $B$ from $\beta$, $U=\cup B, B\in \beta$ and $\bar B$ is compact.
Let $x \in U$ and let $U'$ be the compact nbhd of $x$, since $U$ is open then $U$ is not the singleton set since we are in $T_2$, therefore there is at least another element $y$ in $U$ and $x\neq  y$, and since we are in $T_2$ there exist a open nbhd of $y$, say $V$ that is disjoint from $U$, and let $V'$ be the compact nbhd of $y$..Now I'm lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$The start of your argument doesn’t match the direction that you say that you’re trying to prove. For the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ you don’t have a base of open sets with compact closure: you have to construct one on the assumption that $X$ is locally compact and $T_2$.

HINT: Suppose that $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a locally compact $T_2$-space. Then each $x\in X$ has a compact nbhd $N_x$. Let $U_x=\operatorname{int}N_x$; then $U_x$ is an open nbhd of $x$, and $\cl U_x\subseteq N_x$, so $\cl U_x$ is compact and therefore $T_3$ (why?). Use this to show that $X$ itself is $T_3$. Now let $$\mathscr{B}=\{V\in\tau:\cl V\text{ is compact}\}\;,$$ and show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $\tau$. That is, show that if $x\in U\in\tau$, then there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.

The other direction is trivial: for it you assume that the space has a base $\mathscr{B}$ of open sets with compact closure and show that each point of $X$ has a compact nbhd.

Comment: Thank you Brian, you're always so helpful. I do not understand why the cl U_x is in N_x and I cannot think why this is T3 now.I am trying hard:(

Comment: @Klara: You’re welcome, as always. $U_x\subseteq N_x$, so $\cl U_x\subseteq\cl N_x$. But $N_x$ is closed, so $\cl N_x=N_x$, and therefore $\cl U_x\subseteq N_x$. For the other part, have you seen the proof that a compact Hausdorff space is regular?

Comment: Brian I did find the theorem that compact T2 is normal, so of course  that would be regulae as well. So we are in T4 now. So compact nbhds in T2 are always closed then:).

Answer (score 0):

HINT： $x$ has a compact nbhd $U$, where $\overline{U}$ is compact; then $\exists B \in \mathcal B$, such that $x \in B \subseteq U$. So $\overline{B}$ is also compact, since $\overline{B} \subseteq \overline{U}$.